# Any ideas on how to speed up this query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, leaderboard

I have a leaderboard that runs off of mysql and all my games connect to it. A query similar to this gets called millions of times per day. The only thing that changes is the users score and the appID depending on the game. This query pulls the users rank from the app they are playing. I already have an index on score and appID.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users_scores WHERE score > 13956 AND appID='60'
```

It's a rather basic query so I'm not sure if there is much that can be done in the way of the query itself. The table itself has around 2.2 million records and growing every day. I'm wondering if it would be wise to maybe add a column to the table called rank and then have a cron update all the ranks every 5 minutes or so. The server would be under heavy load when updating all the ranks but would it be better then running that query 90+ times per second?

Or do you maybe have another idea in mind that I'm not thinking of?

Edit Here is the table setup

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_scores` (
  `deviceID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `appID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `score` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `userData` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deviceID`,`appID`),
  KEY `user_score` (`appID`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;;
```

Here is the EXPLAIN of the query above

[image]

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: How many times do the score card gets updated? if the frequency of update is less than frequency of showing leaderboard, you might think of storing rank corresponding to a user and updating the rank everytime score changes

Comment: @AndyLester okay I uploaded the table structure and explain on the query

Comment: @vishva The score table gets updated all the time. Whenever a user views the leaderboard they submit their score and it updates the table. With that being said I have a cron run that caches the top 30 scores into a json file and when the user loads the leaderboards they will see that cached json file not a live query of the table. Updating the rank everytime their rank changes would be too taxing on the db I think.

Answer (score 3):

have a compound index on your table on (appID, score)

This way, the where clause will jump directly to your AppID 60, then subsequently to the score 13956 and get only those higher.  It doesn't have to go back to the raw data pages to qualify since you are doing a count(*).

Comment: Yeah I didn't even realize that until I posted the table structure. What would be the best move, remove the indexes and use the primary key?

Comment: @Dave, the primary key, I would leave based on the unique ID as-is.  I would only create the SECOND index as both columns, but keeping the AppID in the first position, score in the second.

Comment: okay I edited the table in my first post how does that look now?

Comment: @Dave, looks fine... in this case, it is both a compound index AND covering index in case you wanted to look into those terms :)

Comment: `device_id` is a UUID?  If so, the `PRIMARY KEY` sucks.  I am .  UUIDs are _very_ random.  This hurts INSERTs and SELECTs.  And it is disaster when the table gets bigger than can be cached in the buffer_pool.

Comment: Your one SELECT is protected from the suckiness of the PK, because as @DRapp points, you now have a "covering index".  This implies that it does not need to reach for the PK.

Comment: @RickJames Yeah my primary key is a UUID. Should I replace that PK with just an auto increment int and put a unique index on the deviceID and appID?

Comment: Then you are merely moving the suckiness from the `PRIMARY KEY` to a `UNIQUE` index -- nothing saved.

Comment: @RickJames I like your style say what's wrong without giving any advice on how to fix it. What is your suggestion? I have to have a unique way to identify a user without having any access to the database at all. It also has to be something that will be on the user side. I can't just assign them the next available number.

Comment: Sorry.  UUIDs is a problem for which I don't yet have a solution.  There is a partial solution here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid  But it may not help.  If you don't have too many rows (or you have lots of RAM), UUIDs are not really a performance problem.